# Replace an output result

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Get-Backup Database01 | fl

```
Name   : Database01
ID     : 1263232392323
Status : 1
```

How can I replace the "1" of status by the word "Available" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Get-Backup Database01 | fl Name,ID, @{n="Status";e={ if ($_.status -eq 1) { "Available" }}}
```

Comment: You should also include the else clause. If the value of Status is not 1 the Status field will be empty